# Yii ajax file upload

Tags: ajax, file-upload, yii

I need to upload image with ajax call. But POST field with image always is empty. Part of my form:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'logo'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::textField('test', 'test'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Upload'); ?>        
    <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Upload ajax', '#');?>
</div>
```

If i click `submitButton`, then i have both `test` and `logo` fields - image uploaded.
And if i click `ajaxSubmitButton`, then i have only `test` field, `logo` is empty. What is the solution?

PS: i need non-extension solution.

Comment: Try this 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/624/upload-image-and-content-using-ajax-and-store-it-in-different-table/

Comment: have you added `'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'` to the htmlOptions of your form widget?

Comment: @deacs yes, of course

Comment: @SujeetKumar thanks. Unfortunately in my project i need ie8+

Comment: @f0rtis Oh , But still you can use simple php-ajax-jquery uploaders like,
http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery

Comment: it is $_FILES not $_POST !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot upload files with `ajaxSubmitButton` by default. Use simple submit or some uploader.
If you want to upload image via ajax, here's example:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Upload ajax', '#', array("onclick"=>"js:upload_file(this)"));?>
```

In your js:

```
function upload_file(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    var e = document.getElementById("Model_logo");
    fd.append( "Model[logo]", $(e)[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) { 

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR in upload");
        }
    });
}
```

Change Model to your model name and this will work. Also now you can append any data to FormData and it will be passed in $_POST and your file in $_FILES.
Be carefull, this way doesn't work on ie7 and ie8 as i remember.

Answer (score 1):

Based on **ineersa**'s answer, I made some improvements:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Upload ajax', '#', array("onclick"=>"upload_file()")); ?>
```

In your js:

```
function upload_file(){
    var fd = new FormData($('#model-form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) { 

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR in upload");
        }
    });
}
```

This way you don't have to append each form field manually. All form data will be read automatically (including files). Just make sure that `#model-form` is changed according to your form id.

Answer (score 0):

A way you don't need to call $.ajax(...) by yourself.

```js
$(document).on('ajaxBeforeSend', 'form.my-form', function (event, jqXHR, settings) {
    if ((settings.url.indexOf("js_skip") == -1) && $("form.my-form input[type=file]")[0].files.length) {
        jqXHR.abort();
        settings.cache = false;
        settings.contentType = false;
        settings.processData = false;
        settings.data = new FormData(this);
        settings.url = settings.url + "&js_skip=1";
        jqXHR = $.ajax(settings);
    }
});
```